# Calculate by hand fourier transform of this sort of.

Tags: calculus, fourier-analysis

$$x(t)= A+ A_1\sin (2 \pi f t + \theta ) + A_2\cos (2 \pi f_1 t + \theta )$$
I want to  find the Fourier transform  $|\mathcal{F}[x(t)]|^2$ . Is this possible by hand? I can find the Fourier transform but then raise to power seems difficult.Is there any shortcut for this ?

Comment: Have you tried the various formulae for the various products $\cos x \sin y,$ etc?

Comment: I'm confused. Are you trying to calculate $\mathcal{F}\{x(t)\}$ and then square it?

Comment: @Pragabhava yes but the real part :)

Answer (score 1):

Try using convolution rule (specific for this case): $\mathcal{F}[x(t)]\cdot\mathcal{F}[x(t)]=\frac{1}{2\pi}\mathcal{F}[x(t)\ast x(t)]$.